# How-to use C# openapi-generator without SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, openapi-generator

I'm using openapi-generator to create a C# class for accessing a REST API. This REST API is http and does not have a SSL certificate.

The generated C# class was done by this command

```
java -jar ./openapi-generator-cli.jar generate 
-g csharp 
-i ../../openapi.yaml 
-o cn_http_client_csharp 
--additional-properties=artifactId=http-client 
--additional-properties=io.swagger.parser.util.RemoteUrl.trustAll=true 
--additional-properties=io.swagger.v3.parser.util.RemoteUrl.trustAll=true 
--skip-validate-spec
```

When testing this class with another C# application, I always get the following exception
"The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."

I tried to use some tipps from openapi-generator wiki, but I can't fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.

- updated my local openapi generator to version 7.0.1
- generate solution by shell script by pointed targetFramework `net6.0`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dio.swagger.parser.util.RemoteUrl.trustAll=true -Dio.swagger.v3.parser.util.RemoteUrl.trustAll=true"
java -jar /home/user/Projects/OpenApiGenerator/openapi-generator-cli-7.0.1.jar generate -g csharp -i /home/user/Projects/swagger.json -o /home/user/Projects/SwaggerCodeGen --additional-properties=useDateTimeOffset=true,targetFramework=net6.0
```

- then add builded `.dll's` in my project
- create apiInstance

```js
var apiInstance = new AuthApi(new Configuration { 
            BasePath = _gatewayBasePath, 
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (_, _, _, _) => { return true;}
        });
```

- Warning: this solution not work with asynchronous methods of apiInstance, because openapi repository have [bug](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/14608#issuecomment-1768118232)